# Extracting values from String array from JWT object in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, json, list

So I am getting my JWT token with SecurityContext like so:

```
JwtAuthenticationToken authToken = (JWTAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

if (authToken != null) {
    log.warn("Principal authorities:");
    authToken.getAuthorities().forEach(auth -> log.warn("authorities: [{}]", auth.getAuthority()));

Map<String, Object> attributes = Collections.emptyMap();
attributes = authToken.getTokenAttributes();
```

with my token looking something like:

```
{
  "exp": 1705347941,
  "iat": 1705347641,
  "jti": "011200ff-9c3d-44e4-8f49-be29fc0f7792",
  ...
  "user": [
    "backend",
    "backend-time"
  ],
  ...
```

How would grab all the values in `user` and assign them to a array of type String?

I am consoling my values like, but having trouble creating an string array with all `user` values.

```
attributes
    .entrySet()
    .forEach(attr -> log.warn("attributes: [{}:{}", attr.getKey(), attr.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
attributes = authToken.getTokenAttributes();
List<String> userData = (List<String>) attributes.get("user");
```

The `.get()` lets you get whatever data `attributes` contains. The code expects for that to be Object, therefore you have to add `(List<String>)` before getting the data, so the code knows that it is a list of string you will receive.

Then all the strings within user is stored in said list. You could print the data any of these two ways:

```
// To get first element
log.warn(userData(0));

// To get all elements
for (int i = 0; i < userData.size(); i++) {
    log.warn(userData.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract claims like below using the JWT token.

```
    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
    return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(getSigningKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody();
}
```

You will get a list like below.

[image]

You can use the below dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```